# Java 8 Streams API functions

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I am new to Java 8 Streams API. I was working with `forEach` and `filter` and noticed that the following piece of code can be modified with either to produce the same result. In that case, how are the two different and how to decide when to use which?

```
items.forEach(item -> {
    if (item.contains("B") {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
});
```

```
items
    .filter(item -> item.contains("B"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have the same effect.

The difference is that the piece of code calling `filter` uses the stream's filtering operation, whereas `forEach` with the `if` statement uses a plain old `if` statement.

Which one to use depends on what style you want to apply, but the *functional programming* paradigm, the style of the latter piece of code, has become more popular recently.

---

I personally would use

```
items
    .filter(item -> item.contains("B"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

as I find this much better readable.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from readability: for the second version, the two calls can be parallelized, which is relevant especially if both the filter and the output can take some time.

Imagine the filter checks a database with a call that takes 5 seconds, and instead of printing to the console, you upload something to a server which also takes 5 seconds.

In your first version, the stream pipeline will need to spend 10 seconds within the `forEach` call (if an output happens, obviously).

In the second version, after one element has passed the filter call, another element can be filtered, while the first is being output; that means that the whole process takes only 15 seconds instead of 20 in this case.

Comment: `forEach` does not guarantee execution order, so the chosen approach would not affect performance here. If `forEachOrdered` was used I guess it could make a difference indeed.

Comment: @DidierL `forEach` doesn not need to guarantee execution order for it to make a difference. It might only do so in a parallel stream though.

Comment: I meant in a parallel context: `forEachOrdered` cannot be processed in parallel, since it enforces execution order. In that case, a separate `filter()` might allow some parallelism. However, with a simple `forEach`, everything can be parallelised, so it does not matter whether you use a separate `filter()` or not.

Answer (score -1):

The grammar is different but the result is the same :)! The forEach(..) grammar is clear. The filter grammar is hidden by your lambda  item -> item.contains("B").
Without the lambda, .filter would take an instance of a 'Predicate' for example:

```
public Class MyPredicate<String> implements Predicate {
  @Override
  public boolean test(String myString) {
    return myString.contains("B");
  }
}
```

Which you would use like this - .filter(new MyPredicate()).

Comment: You shouldn't write that: at the very least, write `return myString.contains("B");` instead of the useless `if/else`.